# Select is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting: '(', WITH

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I get a syntax error with my SQL statement and I don't know where it is wrong. I'll greatly appreciate it if anyone here can shed some light. Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT YEAR(co.CO_APPLIED_DT) as SCO_YEAR
      ,MONTH(co.CO_APPLIED_DT) as SCO_MONTH_ID
      ,co.CO_OWNER_ACCNID as SCO_APPL_ACCNID
      ,co.CO_APPROVER_ACCNID as SCO_APPR_ACCNID
      ,co.CO_ISSUE_CTRY_CD as SCO_ISSUE_CTRY_CD
      ,co.CO_FINALDEST_CTRY_CD as SCO_DEST_CTRY_CD
      ,'99999999' AS SCO_HS_CHAP_CD
      ,SUM(CASE
             WHEN co.CO_STATUS IN ('A','P', 'T', 'E', 'C', 'F', 'L') THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS SCO_APPROVED_CT
      ,SUM(CASE
             WHEN co.CO_STATUS = 'U' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS SCO_CANCELLED_CT
      ,SUM(CASE
             WHEN co.CO_STATUS = 'R' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS SCO_REJECTED_CT
      ,0 AS SCO_HS_CHAP_CT
  FROM TDocCo co
 WHERE co.CO_STATUS NOT IN ('N', 'D')
   AND co.CO_APPLIED_DT <= :date
   AND YEAR(co.CO_APPLIED_DT) = :year
   AND MONTH(co.CO_APPLID_DT) = :month
 GROUP BY co.CO_APPROVER_ACCNID
         ,co.CO_OWNER_ACCNID
         ,co.CO_ISSUE_CTRY_CD
         ,co.CO_FINALDEST_CTRY_CD
         ,YEAR(co.CO_APPLIED_DT)
         ,MONTH(co.CO_APPLIED_DT);
```

I'm getting the error message as shown above.

Comment: please report the error message. I suppose  :date ,  :year and  :month   are external parameters

Comment: Here is the error msg I got:
Select is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting: '(', WITH

Comment: I reproduced on my local SQL your query, the only error I see is a typo:  AND MONTH(co.**CO_APPLID_DT**)    insead of    AND MONTH(co.**CO_APPLIED_DT**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are my 2 cents:
In my local Db I wrote your query, only changing parameters  :date :year and :month  with today values.  It seems right!

```
 SELECT 
    getDate() as CO_APPLIED_DT,
     23 as CO_OWNER_ACCNID,
     42 as CO_APPROVER_ACCNID,
    'England' as CO_ISSUE_CTRY_CD,
    'Poland' as CO_FINALDEST_CTRY_CD,
    'A' as CO_STATUS 
   INTO TDocCo

SELECT  YEAR(co.CO_APPLIED_DT) as SCO_YEAR, 
    MONTH(co.CO_APPLIED_DT) as SCO_MONTH_ID, 
    co.CO_OWNER_ACCNID as SCO_APPL_ACCNID, 
    co.CO_APPROVER_ACCNID as SCO_APPR_ACCNID, 
    co.CO_ISSUE_CTRY_CD as SCO_ISSUE_CTRY_CD, 
    co.CO_FINALDEST_CTRY_CD as SCO_DEST_CTRY_CD, 
    '99999999' AS SCO_HS_CHAP_CD, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN co.CO_STATUS IN ('A','P', 'T', 'E', 'C', 'F', 'L') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SCO_APPROVED_CT,  
    SUM(CASE WHEN co.CO_STATUS = 'U' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SCO_CANCELLED_CT, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN co.CO_STATUS = 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SCO_REJECTED_CT,
    0 AS SCO_HS_CHAP_CT 
  FROM TDocCo co 
  WHERE co.CO_STATUS NOT IN ('N', 'D')
     AND co.CO_APPLIED_DT <=   getDate()                -- modified 
     AND YEAR(co.CO_APPLIED_DT) =  year (getDate())     -- modified 
     AND MONTH(co.CO_APPLIED_DT) =  month (getDate())   -- modified 
  GROUP BY co.CO_APPROVER_ACCNID, co.CO_OWNER_ACCNID, co.CO_ISSUE_CTRY_CD, co.CO_FINALDEST_CTRY_CD, YEAR(co.CO_APPLIED_DT), MONTH(co.CO_APPLIED_DT);

 DROP TABLE  TDocCo
```

Comment: Thanks, mate. Yes, apparently it works at the end after changing the parameter to today's date and remove the : symbol. Thanks so much!! :)

Comment: @vlina . . . The question is tagged MySQL, yet this code doesn't run in MySQL because `getdate()` is not defined.  It confuses me why you accepted it.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff you are right. I tryed to solve the question in my SQL system.  Feel free to edit using correct grammar. Cheers.

Comment: He was right at the part that I gotta put in the date parameter. I didn't exactly use the getDate() but I changed the date to yesterday's date values, etc . Also, i removed the : symbol just like what he showed.Change the getDate() to just the date value itself, and it worked